# Загрузка файла с большим размером на сервер

Tags: php, ajax

Пытаюсь загрузить файл размером **150мб** получаю ошибку **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** дело в коде или же на самом хостинге ?

```
$data = array();

set_time_limit(3600);

if( isset( $_GET['uploadfiles'] ) ){


    $error = false;
    $files = array();

    $uploaddir = '../inc/uploads/'; 

    if( ! is_dir( $uploaddir ) ) mkdir( $uploaddir, 0777 );

    foreach( $_FILES as $file ){
        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . basename($file['name']) ) ){
            $files[] = $file['name'];
        }
        else{
            $error = true;
        }
    }

    $data = $error ? array('error' => 'Ошибка загрузки файлов.') : array('files' => $files );

    echo json_encode( $data );
}
```

.htaccess

```
php_value max_execution_time 9999
php_value max_input_time 9999
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value memory_limit 50G
```

Comment: скорее всего проблема в веб-сервере, там тоже может быть выставлено ограничение

Comment: Да я так и подумал но вить я изменил ограничение php.ini

Answer (score 1):

`memory_limit 50G`? Лол...

**С кодом все хорошо.**

Помните что `memory_limit` > `post_max_size` > `upload_max_filesize`.

Ограничение может быть где угодно вебсервер, балансировщик, мэнэджер ресурсов...

Вас могут ограничивать по трафику, по времени исполнения скрипта, по количеству используемых ресурсов.

Ищите нормального провайдера.